# Remove duplicated rows from a Merge of two dataframes in r by Date/TIme

Tags: r, date

I have merged two dataframes by date and time in R (by DateTime). One dataframe is a simple sequence, and the other has data for 6242 obs, but I need data for every hour (even if it is zero)

When I merged, my result duplicated rows that matched, instead of inserting them. Is there an addition to the merge function I can use to keep ALL rows, but not those that have duplicated dates with no information? i.e I want row 1933 NOT 1934.

```
x <- data.frame (DateTime = seq(as.POSIXct("1986-01-01"),
                            as.POSIXct("2012-04-27"),
                            by=(3600)))
y <- read.csv("TS1.csv", header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
names(y) <- c("Date", "Time", "Rainfall")

y$Station<- rep("D1253",length(6242))

#reformat so date is the same
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
y$DateTime <-  paste(y$Date, y$Time, sep=" ")

>head(y)
    Date  Time Rainfall Station         DateTime
1 1986-01-01 21:00     0.01   D1253 1986-01-01 21:00
2 1986-01-02  9:00     0.01   D1253  1986-01-02 9:00
3 1986-01-02 10:00     0.01   D1253 1986-01-02 10:00
4 1986-01-02 11:00     0.01   D1253 1986-01-02 11:00
5 1986-01-02 12:00     0.01   D1253 1986-01-02 12:00
6 1986-01-02 13:00     0.01   D1253 1986-01-02 13:00

#Combine datasets 
z<- merge(x, y, by='DateTime', all=TRUE) #the all.x=TRUE gives me all NAs

z$Rainfall[is.na(z$Rainfall)] <- 0.00

> head(z)
             DateTime      Date     Time     Rainfall Station
1933   1986-03-14 18:00:00 1986-03-14 18:00     0.01   D1253
1934   1986-03-14 19:00:00       <NA>  <NA>     0.00    <NA>
1935   1986-03-14 19:00:00 1986-03-14 19:00     0.01   D1253
1936   1986-03-14 20:00:00       <NA>  <NA>     0.00    <NA>
1937   1986-03-14 20:00:00 1986-03-14 20:00     0.01   D1253
1938   1986-03-14 21:00:00       <NA>  <NA>     0.00    <NA>
1939   1986-03-14 21:00:00 1986-03-14 21:00     0.09   D1253
1940   1986-03-14 22:00:00       <NA>  <NA>     0.00    <NA>
1941   1986-03-14 22:00:00 1986-03-14 22:00     0.02   D1253
1942   1986-03-14 23:00:00       <NA>  <NA>     0.00    <NA>
```

Comment: we don't have `TS1.csv`. Please do `dput(y)` and then in your problem statement issue as `y <- whateverThatdputIs`

Comment: also, look into `dplyr::left_join()`

Comment: why are you doing `y$Station <- rep("D1253", length(6242)`? That's the same as doing `rep("D1253",1)`

Comment: I think there is too much data to do `dput(y)`? 6242 specific rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dates have to be formatted the same using `as.POSIXct`

Once that is done, the merge is done correctly with `all.x=TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

**all.x = TRUE** is the right way to go about this:

```
z <- merge(x, y, by='DateTime', all.x = TRUE)
z[is.na(z)] <- 0 # Fill in the NA's with 0 for the hours with no data
```

Comment: all.x=TRUE returns the correct number of rows, but provides all NAs for rainfall data.

Comment: yes then the second line fills those NA's in with 0.

Comment: Yes, but all the data are NAs. It does not merge the rainfall data from dataframe y.